# Are online bachelor's degrees offered on Coursera the exact same as offline degrees?

Tags: bachelor, online-learning, online-degree

The University of London is offering a [bachelor's degree in computer science](https://www.coursera.org/degrees/bachelor-of-science-computer-science-london). It costs over 10k GBP and only opens application twice a year to high school graduates and beyond. Does it have the exact same value as attending the university physically? Can I find good jobs in the US, Canada, UK, etc. with it? This could be my only opportunity to get a bachelor's degree abroad without spending tons of money. (I'm Chinese.)

Comment: Honestly I hope there are not but I am an old person. Though remote learning, as we unfortunately see these days, it is a real thing.

Comment: This is not an answer because I can't address the comparative value. However, the University of London is a real university (not a diploma mill) with a substantial distance learning program. So it is a real degree. I suggest you contact the admissions staff to ask if there is any difference in the way the degree is awarded (eg in the academic transcript) between campus and distance students.

Comment: You might get the same diploma (ask the university) but it cannot be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not be *exactly* the same syllabus and teaching material as a conventional degree, but it is a valid, accredited UK degree offered by the University of London (founded by Royal Charter in 1836). The University and its member institutions have over 50,000 students studying by distance learning, in 190 countries.

Note that 50% of the assessment is by exam at one of their approved centres worldwide.

Whether it will be viewed as equivalent to a degree taught by attendance depends on the employer. Some employers will add some value to a degree studied part-time by distance learning, others will prefer to see physical attendance.

Comment: Thank you. They say they award the same bachelor's degree as an on-campus degree. You can even spend a year or two on campus, and they invite you to the graduation ceremony. I'm going to give it a shot.